# Trying to give HTML5 video a memory through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a html5 video player on my page, this one has a seekbar. Now what I want to achieve here is to give it a var memory that if the video was paused, and then dragged the seekbar, it remains paused, and vise versa if play, after usage seek continue playing...

I have this feeling I messed up because there are if else statements which only load the var once and not after the change of it...

By the way, everything is in a windows.onload function which might cause load the var once but not the change I've put through later?

```
// **Memory**

    var memory = 0;

// **Event listener for the play/pause button**

    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.paused == true) {
            // Play the video
            video.play();
            memory = 1;
        
        // Update the button text to 'Pause'
        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        // Pause the video
        video.pause();
        memory = 0;

        // Update the button text to 'Play'
        playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
});

// **Play or pause the video when the seek handle is dropped according to var memory**

seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    if (memory == 0) {
        // pause if prev state was pause
        video.pause();
    } else if (memory == 1){
        // play if prev state was playing
        video.play();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create event listeners specific to media elements, not just generic things like `click`. You can find a full list of the media events and methods, with descriptions, in [the MSDN document here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/liBRary/ff975073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That should have everything available to you when you're working with an HTML5 video element.

Comment: None of those (as far as i can tell) seem to sort of memorise the previous state ( in this case as the seekbar is dragged)  ?